# Gyroscope doesn't support Sensor Batching Nexus 5x running Android 6.0?

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors, gyroscope, batching

Calling both sensor.getFifoMaxEventCount()) and sensor.getFifoReservedEventCount()) both return 0 which is suppose to mean the sensor doesn't support batching. Yet my accelerometer supports batching using the same methods. Anyone know why such an important sensor like the gyro doesn't support batching?

Edit: Compass has same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Android 6.0... seems it doesn't support sensor batching anymore.